# Why do we use this in web.xml

Tags: rest, jersey

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I removed the above from web.xml, i was getting some error. Can someone explain the purpose of POJOMapping feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the JAX-RS built-in support for converting your plain old java object into JSON string, then you should enable this.

Refer the below snippet from the resource class

```
    //com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature = true
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Data getAllData() {
        Data data = myService.getAllData();
        return data;
    }
    //JAX-RS takes care of converting Data object into JSON string.
```